# Regex to group words separated by space

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a data frame, in which one column is a Series of strings, in which distinct phrases are either single words or multiple words separated by spaces; and the first letter of each individual word is upper case (e.g. "Strawberry" or "Strawberry Jam", respectively). In contrast, if not part of the same phrase, the words are not spaced out (e.g. "JamApple").

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'foo': ['Strawberry JamApple', 'BananaPear CrumblePotato', 'Almond Cake'],
    'bar': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'baz': [1, 2, 3],
    'zoo': ['x', 'y', 'z'],
})


                        foo bar  baz zoo
0       Strawberry JamApple   A    1   x
1  BananaPear CrumblePotato   B    2   y
2               Almond Cake   C    3   z
```

How could I use regex to separate phrases in a string based on the rule above (into "Strawberry Jam", "Apple", "Banana", "Pear Crumble", "Potato", "Almond Cake"). and extract them? I.e., get the following data frame:

```
   foo
0  Strawberry Jam
0  Apple
1  Banana
1  Pear Crumble
1  Potato
2  Almond Cake
```

I started with the following code:

```
df.loc[:, 'foo'].str.extractall('([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+)').copy()
```

However, this separates all words and doesn't use space to "connect" them. How would I include the latter?

Thanks.

Comment: `'([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+)'` -> `r'([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+( [A-Z]{1}[a-z]+)*)'` - one word + 0-or-more space+word things https://regex101.com/r/FrLJfX/1

Comment: This works only if there are max 2 phrases in the cell, though. E.g., if instead of "Strawberry JamApple" we had "Strawberry JamApple PieSalmonHamburger", it would not extract "Salmon" and "Hamburger".

Comment: Works for me on regex101? 4 matches for "Strawberry JamApple PieSalmonHamburger" -> "Strawberry Jam", "Apple Pie", "Salmon", "Hamburger". I assumed df's extractall works like re.findall

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) + [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html)

```
df['foo'].str.split(r'(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])').explode()
```

---

```
0    Strawberry Jam
0             Apple
1            Banana
1      Pear Crumble
1            Potato
2       Almond Cake
Name: foo, dtype: object
```

**Regex details:**

- `(?<=[a-z])` : Positive Lookbehind matches the single character in the range `a` to `z`
- `(?=[A-Z])`  : Positive Lookahead matches the single character in the range `A` to `Z`

See the [`regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/JryqdB/1/)

Comment: Oh man, my regexfu is not a strong as yours.  Positive Lookbehind.  Great.  I will use this in the future!  Very very nice.  +1